# Sub domain issue in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

So we have many issues with the sub-domain that we are using with the marketing cloud. One of them is: If we want to reply to the emails from Outlook, we get an error message that says:

Undelivarable and the content is: reply-fecc157376670c7c-2139_HTML-104564539-100025066-1 wasn't found at hello.ourSubdomain.com.

Also every time a client replies to one of our emails, @hello.ourSubdomain.com is getting appended at the end of their actual email address. We did whitelist our IP address and this was resolved for 2 days. But later, we started getting the same errors.

marketing-cloud

Comment: i posted it again because no one answered my question days ago

Comment: I am not sure if you could start a bounty with your current score. If yes, you should do that on your previous post.

Comment: Have you pushed this issue to SFMC Global Support? They would be able to better assist you on issues like this where it seems to be an account setting that is not quite correct.